# How to read large file using multiple thread in java?

Tags: java

How to read large file using multiple thread in java?
I'm using while loop for reading file line by line

Comment: Are you sure that you can read that fast from the device where the file is stored?

Comment: Hint: do a bit of prior research the next time. What makes you think that you are the first person that has such a question?

Comment: Spacetracker file stored in my pc

Comment: Stephen c where can I find solution ?